# ui-select was not working properly

Tags: angularjs, ui-select

I'm using **ui-select** for auto complete, it's working for if i select the options from list but it's not working when i select the options from matched query list.

```
<ui-select ng-model="mycontroller.country" name="country">
    <ui-select-match placeholder="country">
        <span data-ng-bind="$select.selected.country_id"></span>
    </ui-select-match>
    <ui-select-choices repeat="country in mycontroller.countries | filter: $select.search | orderBy: 'country_id' | unique: 'country_id'">
        <span data-ng-bind="country.country_name"></span>
    </ui-select-choices>
</ui-select>
```

And this is my js

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngSanitize', 'ui.select']);

angular.module('app').controller('mycontroller', ['$scope', function ($scope){
var self= this;
self.countries = [
    {id: 1, name: 'india'},
    {id: 2, name: 'spain'},
    {id: 3, name: 'malasiya'},
    {id: 4, name: 'ithali'},
    {id: 5, name: 'usa'},
];
```

Please help me, Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that there is no country array `$scope.country= ""` for it to store the value that is being selected. If you can initiate an empty object it will work fine. And also using $scope is encouraged than using the approach that you are using.